# Add CSS to any <div> in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a `.bg` class. I want it to be in a specific div, but I can not access it through modules. This pic shows all module-connections, and a blue-color marked "needed div":

[image]

So, I can jump right into source code of the already connected classes, but they all are used in other structures in this template.

Any ideas?
Love to you, Michael.

Comment: Can you not access the HTML structure itself? Simply add `class="bg"` to the DIV you wish to have the class you've created.

Comment: @ObsidianAge As the site is in joomla, it is using a framework. Is there a way to do so? Please share!

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your sreenshot, but you can use like this:

```
div.outerdiv > div {values from .bg}
```

Comment: you can open in new tab, it's good-looking there. And btw, where should I input this line? The class of blue line marked on screenshot is not editable through Class Suffix Module of that exact module (the editable ones are children-divs of the NEEDED one)

Comment: simple add "div.sparky_container > div" or. "div.sparky_cell" to your main .css file. You can see the css path on the buttom of your screen shot

Comment: or better modify the div.sparky in the css file of the component with a override.

Comment: You can also override the layout of the module.